# How to automate Outlook to reply to mail outside of working hours?

Tags: vba, outlook

My PC is always on, and Outlook is always open. I want to write a macro that replies to any sender if a mail is received outside of working hours, every day.

The out of office auto reply's date and time range is too limited for this.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Have you tried nothing yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    If Now() > DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) _
            ) + #5:00:00 PM# _
        Or Now() < DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) _
            ) + #7:00:00 AM# Then

        ' your code here

    End If
End Sub
```

See here  [Outlook Reply or ReplyAll to an Email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31818677/4539709)

Comment: Thanks for this. I changed the OR to AND, Works great