# Outlook VBA - Automate Replies in Specific Folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

First time poster and new to Outlook VBA.

I currently have a rule that moves all incoming mail that contains the string “Apple” in the body to a specific folder.
I ultimately want this:

On any new email that gets moved to that folder, if the body does NOT contain the word “fruit” then reply with “Deny”, a line break and then a couple sentences. The original subject and body should remain. It would act the same as if I hit the “Reply” button.

I’m getting stuck here, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31818677/4539709

Comment: Thanks, that'll work!