# How can I reply email using vbs

Tags: outlook, vbscript

I'm trying to get mailitem by `Outlook.application` object, and reply email by certain subject naming rule.
Now I'm able to get the mailitem, filter the mail by its subject. How can I move the next step to `reply` email? Thanks

Belo is my code so far:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MailItem = objOutlook.Session.Folders("XXX@XXX.com")
For Each eMail in MailItem.Items
    If InStr(1,Trim(eMail.Subject),"Production",vbTextCompare) > 0 then
    wscript.echo "This is needed email, need to reply"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For wscript use, you can modify the example found in
[Outlook Reply or ReplyAll to an Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817632/outlook-reply-or-replyall-to-an-email)

You pull eMail in your loop of Mail items

Use this in place of wscript.echo line

```
Set olReply = eMail.ReplyAll
olReply.HTMLBody = "Hello, Thank you. " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
olReply.Display
olReply.Send
```

Comment: I replace the code of wscript.echo line and it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent - please mark it as an answer then - welcome to Stack Overflow